# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet;

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, h2

I am writing a unit test for a custom query in my repository in Spring. I am using an h2 in-memory database to create an employee and perform an assertion on that employee which should be returned from the custom query.
When I call the save method from my repository the following error is thrown:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I will include my pom.xml as well as the code for my repository and test.

Unit Test

```
package com.stg.mlindow.javabootrestcert.stgbootrestcert.employee;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@DataJpaTest
class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    void findAllByBossId() {
        Employee employee = new Employee(
                "CEO",
                "Bruce",
                "Wayne",
                null
        );
        employeeRepository.save(employee);

        List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAllByBossId(null);
        List<Employee> expected = new ArrayList<Employee>() {
            {
                add(employee);
            }
        };

        assertIterableEquals(expected, employees);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.7</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.stg.mlindow.javabootrestcert</groupId>
   <artifactId>stg-boot-rest-cert</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>stg-boot-rest-cert</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
         <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
         <version>0.9.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
         <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
         <version>23.1.0</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

application-test.properties

```
##### Database #####
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
```

Repository

```
package com.stg.mlindow.javabootrestcert.stgbootrestcert.employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, BigInteger>,
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, BigInteger> {
    List<Employee> findAllByBossId(BigInteger bossId);
}
```

I have tried the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952590/org-springframework-dao-invaliddataaccessresourceusageexception-could-not-extra) but it did not fix my problem. I was expecting the test to create an Employee and then try to retrieve that newly created employee from the h2 database by boss id. Then it would assert that the 2 lists are equal.

Comment: To my eyes dialect looks fishy. You are using AutoConfigureTestDatabase (DataJpaTest pulls it in as well), hence you are using h2 with default mode, but you pick postgres dialect.

Comment: I did not know I could do that. How do I do that? @Lesiak

Comment: Sorry mate, I dont get your question. Do what? I was referring to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` property - have you tried with h2 dialect?

Comment: I haven't, I don't know how.

Comment: Can you please share Employee entity class as well?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by fixing an error in my `application-test`.

```
##### Database #####
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2://mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

The `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` needed to be set to the H2Dialect rather than the PostgreSQLDialect.
This was as @Lesiak suspected.